# using variables in aws launch template userdata (terraform)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, launch-template

I am currently creating a launch template using terraform `aws_launch_template` resource. I need to pass in user data and i do so using
`user_data =filebase64("file_path/file_name.sh")`. I need to have variables inside my userdata file (`file_name.sh`). What is the best way to accomplish this ?

Comment: What is your current attempt at `file_name.sh`? Why it does not work? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 3):

You're using templatefile to pass variable, then you'll need the function base64encode to provide user_data required by launch_teamplate. Try this:

```
user_data =  base64encode(templatefile("${path.module}/your-file.sh", {the_var1 = var.the_var1, the_var2= value2}))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the function `templatefile`, since it lets you pass variables to the template file

```
user_data = templatefile("file_path/file_name.sh", { var1 = value1, var2= value2})
```

And to use them to your script

**file_name.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "template vars are: ${var1} , ${var2}"
```

Comment: Thanks , I tired it earlier, but user_data argument is only valid for EC2 and not for launch_template

Comment: @ChoolaiRaj I beg to differ. user_data is also available in launch template take a look below
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_template#user_data

Comment: @ChoolaiRaj, if you're using aws_launch_template then you'll need base64 encoded user data. You can have it using the base64encode function, like: base64encode(templatefile("file_path/file_name.sh", { var1 = value1, var2= value2}))